# Does &'a T imply T: 'a?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, lifetime

From my own understanding and experimentation this appears to be true, but I have yet to find an authoritative source that documents it. Rust by Example has a [bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_bounds.html) section where it says:

> `T: 'a`: All references in `T` must outlive lifetime `'a`.
>
> ```
> #[derive(Debug)]
> struct Ref<'a, T: 'a>(&'a T);
> // `Ref` contains a reference to a generic type `T` that has
> // an unknown lifetime `'a`. `T` is bounded such that any
> // *references* in `T` must outlive `'a`. Additionally, the lifetime
> // of `Ref` may not exceed `'a`.
> ```

However, this looks like a poor demonstration since the `T: 'a` bound does not seem to affect the behavior of `Ref`. Any attempt I've made to construct a `T` that is shorter than `'a` is thwarted with or without `T: 'a`. Even more, a generic reference defined *without* the lifetime bound can be passed off as one *with* it:

```
fn f<'a, T>(r: &'a T) {
    g(r) // this compiles
}

fn g<'a, T: 'a>(r: &'a T) {
    // ...
}
```

The Rust Reference has a similar construction from some examples in the [generic parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html) section (`struct Ref<'a, T> where T: 'a { r: &'a T }`), however it does not elaborate. I have looked through the documentation there, those on references, and on lifetimes and cannot find a link.

So does `&'a T` imply `T: 'a`? If so, where is this documented? And why do these resources have this unnecessary constraint? If not, what are the rules?

Comment: Thanks for starting this topic. It's definitely useful for developers with mid-level Rust experience. I've already spent almost a week reading about this and still things are not clear. I'm unable to come up with a type (for `T`) which does not compile if `T: 'a` constraint isn't used in Ref type you quoted.

Comment: @Nawaz From my answer below, you will find there is no such `T` because the `T: 'a` bound exists regardless due to the usage of `&'a T`. So there is no difference with or without writing it explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `&'a T` does imply `T: 'a`.

There was always the requirement that referent had to outlive the referenced lifetime since it is necessary for safety by-construction. However, before Rust 1.31 the bound was not inferred and would have to be provided explicitly as shown in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626644/why-does-the-rust-compiler-request-i-constrain-a-generic-type-parameters-lifeti) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794800/why-is-the-bound-t-a-required-in-order-to-store-a-reference-a-t).

It was [RFC #2093: infer outlives](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2093-infer-outlives.md) that let the compiler to infer these bounds and thus allowed the user to elide them. Since then, the Rust by Example and Rust Reference snippets are over-specified and the `T: 'a` is no longer needed.

See elsewhere in the Reference on [trait and lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/trait-bounds.html#implied-bounds):

> Lifetime bounds required for types to be well-formed are sometimes inferred.
>
> ```
> fn requires_t_outlives_a<'a, T>(x: &'a T) {}
> ```
>
> The type parameter `T` is required to outlive `'a` for the type `&'a T` to be well-formed. This is inferred because the function signature contains the type `&'a T` which is only valid if `T: 'a` holds.

---

There is at least one place where `&'a T` does not automatically infer `T: 'a` and that is when defining associated types for a trait ([demo on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d4939f399c3b7bdc0eebb4174ca1212)) but the compiler will guide you into adding it explicitly:

```
trait MakeRef<'a> {
    type Type;
}

impl<'a, T> MakeRef<'a> for Vec<T> {
    type Type = &'a T;
}
```

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:17
  |
6 |     type Type = &'a T;
  |                 ^^^^^ ...so that the reference type `&'a T` does not outlive the data it points at
  |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
  |
5 | impl<'a, T: 'a> MakeRef<'a> for Vec<T> {
  |           ++++
```

Comment: Great answer! Is the lack of inference on associated types a bug or intended? If it's the latter, I wonder why it has to be that way.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I pulled that [from the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2093-infer-outlives.md#where-explicit-annotations-would-still-be-required) so its definitely intentional: *"In this case, the impl has two inputs [`MakeRef<'a>` and `Vec<T>`] ... neither of these inputs requires that `T: 'a`"* though I'm not sure if there's a design reason behind preferring it that way or if it is just a technical limitation.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for explaining it and sharing the relevant RFC! Quite useful.